# New facebook application width to be 520px only?

Tags: facebook, fixed-width

I'm about to make a facebook application and I'm confused about what width I can design for. It seems that at the moment you have 760px at your disposal, but a lot of sources say this will be reduced to 520px in the beginning of 2010. Being halfway through 2010 already, I'm wondering if this is really happening? 520px seems very little? Does anyone know if and when the change will happen? What will happen to existing applications that are wider?

Answer (score 2):

The 520px width is in reference the [Application-Specific Tabs](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Tabbed_Profile#Application-Specific_Tabs), not Applications proper.

Applications still use the full 760px width.

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea what they intend, so take this with a pinch of salt. (Similarly, treat any assertions by non-Facebook staff with a heavy amount of cynicism - those crazy Zuckerbergites work in strange ways...)

Anyway, the last time they introduced a new width, they gave developers the option to stick with the old width system.

In fact, that option is still there (in the app settings):

[image: Canvas width option]

Given that that option is still there, I'd cautiously suggest that:

1. They're not realistically planning another change any time soon.
2. If they do, they won't force it on developers

Hope this helps.